# Sum of sines functions - Type error float object is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror, iterable

I am trying to develop a function that calculates the sum of sines.

The first function that I tried was:

```py
def S(t,n,T):
    return (4/pi)*sum((1/(2*i-1))*sin(2*(2*i-1)*pi*t/T) for i in range(1,n+1))
```

and then I got an answer of `0.2381` when I called the function using the arguments below:

```py
S(0.01*2*pi,3,2*pi)
```

As I am relatively new to Python I tried to amend this code to:

```py
def S1(t1,n1,T1):
    
    s1 = 0
    
    for i in range(1,n1+1):
        s1 = s1 + (4/pi)*sum((1/(2*i-1))*sin(2*(2*i-1)*pi*t1/T1))
    return s1
```

but when I call the function S1 using the same arguments I get an error saying that:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.
```

Can someone explain why this is? I reviewed some of the other answers in relation to this `TypeError` but I do not understand them.

Comment: What do you expect to get from `sum((1/(2*i-1)) ...`?

Comment: You may just want to get rid of sum(), since you are explicitly summing in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty trivial: `sum()` requires an iterable as argument, while in `S1` you are passing it a float.

In `S()` it works well since with `for i in...` builds a collection which is then passed to `sum()`, while in the second case you are fixing `i` and getting a float to pass to `sum()` at every cycle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I appreciate the responses which are helping me to learn and hopefully contribute myself in time.

Answer (score 0):

The function `sum()` requires an iterable as argument, but in `S1` you are passing it a float.

Here's the solution:

```
def S1(t1, n1, T1):
    results = []
    for i in range(1, n1 + 1):
        results.append((1 / (2 * i - 1)) * sin(2 * (2 * i - 1) * pi * t1 / T1))
    return (4 / pi) * sum(results)
```